# How to get the maximum and not duplicated data in my table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I table data is like this:

```
id                  car_id                              create_time           remark
6c3befd0201a4691    4539196f55b54523986535539ed7beef    2017-07-1 16:42:49    firstcar
769d85b323bb4a1c    4539196f55b54523986535539ed7beef    2017-07-18 16:42:49   secondcar
984660c4189e499     575d90e340d14cf1bef4349b7bb5de9a    2017-07-3 16:42:49    firstjeep
```

I want to get the newest data. It means if there have two same car_id, I want to get only one according the newest time. How to write?

I try to write this, but I find it may wrong. If the other record may have the same create_time? How to fix that?

```
SELECT * FROM t_decorate_car 
WHERE create_time IN 
    (SELECT tmptime FROM
        (SELECT MAX(create_time),tmptime,car_id
         FROM decorate 
         GROUP BY car_id
        ) tmp
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

One canonical way to handle this is to join your table to a subquery which finds the latest record for each `car_id`.  This subquery serves as a filter to remove the older records you don't want to see.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t_decorate_car t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT car_id, MAX(create_time) AS max_create_time
    FROM t_decorate_car
    GROUP BY car_id
) t2
    ON t1.car_id      = t2.car_id AND
       t1.create_time = t2.max_create_time
```

By the way, if you want to continue down your current road, you can also solve this using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t_decorate_car t1
WHERE t1.create_time = (SELECT MAX(t2.create_time) FROM t_decorate_car t2
                        WHERE t2.car_id = t1.car_id)
```

You were on the right track but you never connected the subquery to the main query using the right `WHERE` clause.